# Setting the height of a Tkinter Label

Tags: python, layout, tkinter, label

I thought this was a very simple procedure.

```
seperator = Label(text ="")
seperator.config(background='#2b5bce', relief = RAISED, Height = 3)
seperator.grid(row=16, column=0, sticky="w", columnspan=40, ipadx = 500)
```

but we get the following error!

```
TclError: bad option "-Height": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky
```

Comment: try lowercase H in height, as far as i'm aware all tkinter arguments are lowercase, i tried it on my pc (using python 3.3.2) and it worked fine using lowercase

Comment: The error doesn't match your code. The error came from a call to `grid`, but your code shows using `Height` in a call to `config`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The options are case-sensitive. You should use `height`, not `Height`.